# Calculate the max speed at which a submarine rises/dives + acceleration

Tags: liquid, water-pressure, submarines

I'm trying to figure out how I would calculate the rate at which a submarine (or any object) ascends or descends in seawater given a certain buoyancy or change in buoyancy. For example, if my submarine is 2000 feet below sea level and weighs 393 metric tons (with empty ballast tanks) and displaces 13,583 cubic feet of water, what's the maximum rate it will rise to the surface (assuming it can reach that rate before breaking the surface) and it's acceleration/deceleration to that rate? I'd like to know if there's a reliable and accurate way to solve a problem like this that takes into account factors like the change in sea water pressure and density with depth, as well as the increase in water resistance against the submarine as it accelerates upward.

Comment: Depth can almost be ignored. It won't affect friction coefficients. It only smooshes the sub a bit smaller, reducing surface area. You may want to handle that as displacement that is a function of depth, though.

Comment: Subs use propulsion and dive planes for attitude control. Unless you are talking about one-trip ballast drop subs.

Comment: I'm talking about an emergency blow procedure, I'm aware thrusters and and dive planes are used for altitude control normally

Comment: I imagine that viscous drag will dominate, so drag is proportional to velocity. The good news from that is that the differential equations are more likely to be solvable. Unfortunately submarines don't necessarily have enough air to blow all of the water out of the ballast tanks at depth, so water continues to be expelled as the sub rises, in an efficient maneuver the tanks just empty as the sub surfaces. So you need to decide on how you will model the air volume, which will give you a net buoyancy , and then perhaps https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1946.0059 will help

Comment: So, which scenario are you interested in, the efficient one, partly filling the ballast tank and letting the air expand as it rises, or the simple one where the extra buoyancy is fixed?

Comment: @GregLocock I'm more interested in the efficient method, as it more accurately represents a real scenario

Comment: model the sub as a cylinder. look up coefficient of drag for a cylinder (i.e. relates force to velocity). with flow perpendicular to cylinder axis. then force balance vs the net buoyancy - which based on your previous question I'm guessing you made some decisions about

Comment: depth may have an effect on viscosity, in particular via temperature variation if significant. water visc tempco ~= 2% per deg C at room temp, seawater may vary. there's a slight pressure coefficient too. probably matters rather less than your ability to model the drag coefficient of the sub's shape